TextBox and Listbox
I have a TextBox and a Listbox in EXCEL VBA project. I need to insert value using textbox control.
Every time I click on Enter, the value in the textbox control is added to the listbox below and the textbox control is emptied.
I need to set set focus on the textbox control for a new insertion. I have a problem with the .SetFocus, it does not work! I can't set the .SetFocus on the textbox control after each insertion.
I have also used events _AfterUpdate, _BeforeUpdate, _Change, _Enter, _KeyDown and _KeyUp with the same result.
I used this code
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode <> 13 Then Exit Sub
    
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Text
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub


You are on the right track. No need to set focus back to TextBox1. All you have to do is set the Keycode to 0
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode <> 13 Then Exit Sub
    
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Text
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""

    KeyCode = 0
End Sub


Hi Siddharth Rout, thank you for your interesting alternative!

Hi Siddharth Rout, thank you for your interesting alternative! –  Pasquale Prudente  Commented19 mins ago Alternative? It is not an alternative. It is the right way to handle such things :)

Hi Siddharth Rout, could you explain what   "KeyCode=0" stay for? Thank you in advance.

Before I explain what KeyCode=0 does, let me explain what KeyCode  is. It is an argument passed to the KeyDown event, which allows you to handle keypress events for a control.
The value of KeyCode corresponds to a specific key on the keyboard. For example, the Enter key has a KeyCode value of 13.
Now comes the KeyCode = 0. This prevents the key event from being processed further by other handlers. This means the Enter key will not trigger any default behavior. For example in this case moving to the next control.

Thanks for this complete and helpful explanation

Your code looks mostly correct but I have often found issues with SetFocus in VBA are due to timing or conflicts with how the event is being handled. You need to use a slight delay or verifying that no other control or operation interferes.
Application.OnTime introduces a slight delay before setting the focus back to the TextBox. This will ensure that SetFocus is being executed after all the key-handling events are finished.
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = 13 Then ' Check if Enter key is pressed
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Text ' Add item to ListBox
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "" ' Clear TextBox

        Application.OnTime Now, "SetFocusToTextBox"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetFocusToTextBox()
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub


HI Jacob, thank you very much for your precious help. Now it does work very well! Thank you again!

An alternative is;
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode <> 13 Then Exit Sub
    ListBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    Me.Hide
    Me.Show
End Sub

